# Is the aps-iot-extensions-demo currently down?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-tandem

I'm aware that APS has been undergoing maintenance in the last few days. I'd like to know if the APS IoT extension service (Link below) is currently working as normal. I built an app for my research project on top of this demo earlier this month. But now it has stopped working. I've tried using a different account, APS secret, APS ID, and different models, but the web app only displays the toolbar but doesn't load the model.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

I've noticed that the previous trial account that I managed to get the app to work now has (0 tokens, and 1 consumed in the App analytics pages). The new trial account I've just created has (0 tokens, 0 consumed in the App analytics pages). Please let me know if this is an existing problem with the APS side, or if there is any wrong with my account.

Comment: The old account (0 tokens and 1 consumed )that I have is in a Grace period.

Comment: I got this error in the javascript console
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6b3VvbXZ5cWFjbXN2Z2J6Z2Jtc2l0dTFsdmd5ZWJxZGZ2dGdqd3NndWd5bmFycWZqLWJhc2ljLWFwcC9yYWNiYXNpY3NhbXBsZXByb2plY3QucnZ0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue yesterday. I eventually realized it was related to the latest maintenance that had been carried out, affecting the Viewer. I managed to resolve it using the link:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/getting-404-resource-not-found-error-viewer

Comment: thanks lots, the code works